# Linux (Ubuntu) Terminal Screwey

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, console

CTRL+A, for example, is printing "^A" instead of returning my cursor to the start of the line.

This happens via ssh, in a screen session, or on the hard console. $TERM shows either xterm or linux depending on which one I'm on.

How do I get the keymap fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enabled vi mode for bash somewhere like this "set -o vi"  (probably in your ~/.bashrc file)

You need to remove that line or change to "set -o emacs"

Comment: Yes, it went to vi mode. Can't find WHERE it went to vi mode, especially since `set` alone says nothing about it, but thanks for the fix.